# In mvc application how its finding the view i.e cshtml page when clicking on some button i.e action is happened?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC. I tried one example from w3schools.com

here is the link:
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_database.asp

I have 2 doubts.

Doubt 1:
In this movies tab is there, showing create,edit and delete.
Manually I entered few records in the table directly. When clicking on movies tab it should show the records what I entered directly in table not through application but its not showing.

If I entered records through application  through create link, then its showing those records.
Where I missed the concept?

Doubt 2:

As I told there are create, edit, delete links in movies tab.
When I click on edit tab, it goes to action method and selects the view page.

I understood the action method.
But I did not understand the view page part. 
How its knowing it has to go to Edit.cshtml view page?
Where it is mentioned in the code?

Please clarify my doubts.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no inner join. its a simple table. And I want the code where it is mentioning like it has to go to edit.cshtml when clicking edit link.

Answer (score 0):

Re : Doubt 1 - possibly there is an `INNER join` or such that you've missed out on, and inserted data (e.g. with a null FK) which gets eliminated by a join. Or possibly you've added data to the wrong database / table? You'll also need to refresh your browser after updating data back-end (unless you have some refresh magic like SignalR implemented). But you are right in thinking that it doesn't matter how the data gets into the database.

Re : Doubt 2: MVC is largely convention driven. In the case of Controller actions, the name of the view to be used is assumed to be the same name as the method in the controller, in the folder named the same as the Controller. You'll want to read up on this, e.g. [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-fundamentals)

**Edit**

```
// Views for this Controller should typically in /Views/Home/ (unless you also have areas)
public class HomeController : Controller  
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();  // Will look for Index.cshtml - since this is the method name
  }
```

You can override this by [providing another view name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
return View("Foo"); // Looks for Foo.cshtml
```

Comment: There is no inner join. its a simple table. And I want the code where it is mentioning like it has to go to edit.cshtml when clicking edit link.